# Problems with manipulating the files within a list

Tags: r, lapply, xlsx

I have imported 90 excel files by creating a directory (dir) and using (lapply). I am not sure if this is called a nested list or not. After importing the excel files in a list, I can see that some files have four columns and some other files have five columns. My questions are:

1. How can I cut the files with four columns from this list and paste it into a new list.
2. How can I then combine all the similar column files within a list into a single file.
3. How can I save those two files as two different excel sheets?

```
library(foreign)
setwd("F:\\Spring 2019\\Thesis_data\\Kam_Thesis\\data\\nontidal_water_level")

nontidal_list <- dir(pattern= ".xlsx")

nontidal_water_level <- lapply(nontidal_list, read_excel)
```

Comment: How do you define similar? Similar due to names, data or some other criterion?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You should ask just one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide an example dataset, we'll pretend it looks like this:

```
> nontidal_water_level <- lapply(1:4, function(i) data.frame(matrix(1:12 * i, ncol = 3 + (i %% 2))))
> str(nontidal_water_level)
List of 4
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ X2: int [1:3] 4 5 6
  ..$ X3: int [1:3] 7 8 9
  ..$ X4: int [1:3] 10 11 12
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X1: int [1:4] 2 4 6 8
  ..$ X2: int [1:4] 10 12 14 16
  ..$ X3: int [1:4] 18 20 22 24
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ X1: int [1:3] 3 6 9
  ..$ X2: int [1:3] 12 15 18
  ..$ X3: int [1:3] 21 24 27
  ..$ X4: int [1:3] 30 33 36
 $ :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X1: int [1:4] 4 8 12 16
  ..$ X2: int [1:4] 20 24 28 32
  ..$ X3: int [1:4] 36 40 44 48
```

For question number 1, you can find out the columns of each by looping over and using `ncol`, then putting the dataframes with the same number of columns into individual lists:

```
> ncolumns <- lapply(nontidal_water_level, ncol)
> nontidal_3col <- nontidal_water_level[ncolumns == 3]
> nontidal_4col <- nontidal_water_level[ncolumns == 4]
```

For question number 2, you can call `rbind` over all elements of each list:

```
> (nontidal_3col <- do.call(rbind, nontidal_3col))
  X1 X2 X3
1  2 10 18
2  4 12 20
3  6 14 22
4  8 16 24
5  4 20 36
6  8 24 40
7 12 28 44
8 16 32 48
> (nontidal_4col <- do.call(rbind, nontidal_4col))
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12
4  3 12 21 30
5  6 15 24 33
6  9 18 27 36
```

Finally, for question 3, you could use a package like [writexl](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl), but I would recommend just writing it out as a `.csv`:

```
write.csv(nontidal_3col, "my_3_column_file.csv")
write.csv(nontidal_4col, "my_4_column_file.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop that does the job.

for the three steps:

```
if!require(plyr) install.packages(plyr) 
df_4col <- data.frame() # a dataframe that after function must contain all four columns data
df_5col <- data.frame() # the same eith five colums
df_4list <- c() # a list with the filenames
df_5list <- c() # a list with the filenames

for (i in 1:length(nontidal_list)){
df <- read_excel(nontidal_list[i])
if (length(df)==4) {
    df_4col<-plyr::rbind.fill(df_4col, df) 
    df_4_list<-append(df_4list, nontidal_list[i]} else
if (length(df)==5) {
    df_5col<-plyr::rbind.fill(df_4col, df) 
    df_5list<-append(df_5list, nontidal_list[i]} 
}
```